# Xcode tab switch when error

Tags: tabs, switch-statement, xcode4.5

I get some display issue with Xcode4.5.2
When an error occurs during my code run (whatever it is) the Xcode's tabs switch from the tab I was (most of the timme main.cpp) to another tab displaying the library which has detected a problem.
I would like to diseable this automatic switch.

I tried already many buttons in Xcode>preferences>behavior

But I did not get it yet

Can you help me?
Thanks